# Why is this regex for validating specific domains' emails not working?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the PHP `preg_match` function to validate our company's emails, which can be of the form `user@mycompany.com` or use a subdomain such as `user@marketing.mycompany.com` or `user@it.mycompany.com`.

```
return (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+(\.?mycompany\.com)$/", $testEmail) > 0)
```

However, the validEmail function returns false for all of the above examples I mentioned. Why?

Comment: Are you sure it returns false for *all* of them? I see why it returns false for `user@mycompany.com` and `user@it.mycompany.com` (not enough characters between `@` and `\.?mycompany\.com`), but I would have expected it to work for `user@marketing.mycompany.com` . . .

Comment: I don't believe it works for any of them actually. I just tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?mycompany\.com$
```

- The 3rd and 4th level domains weren't made optional ( `()?` ) which ruled out anything @mycompany.com and @onesubonly.mycompany.com
- You forgot to escape a `.`
- My Syntax check doesn't like the unescaped dash in the first character class, but it shouldn't matter where it is to my knowledge.

Fun thing on the topic of email regexes (seeing "..@mycompany.com" and the like would pass yours):
http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you make the fix suggested by Jack Maney:

After the '@' character is matched, you are matching against

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+(\.?mycompany\.com)$
```

So it will fail to match "blah@mycompany.com" since it MUST match an alphanumeric/hyphen, then a dot, then a letter, and then (.?)mycompany.com. It would match "blah@a.b.mycompany.com"

To fix it, try this regex:

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*mycompany\.com$/
```

Note that now, after the '@', it allows 0 or more instances of

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.
```

which represents a subdomain

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot to escape a `.` and a `-`.  Also, not making the character blocks between `"@"` and `mycompany.com` caused a problem for matching `user@mycompany.com`.  Try:

```
return (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.+]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z])?)?(\.?mycompany\.com)$/", $testEmail) > 0)
```

Comment: @DavidFaux - Try it now.  I tested it out on the three dummy email addresses that you gave in your question, and it works for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is built-in function for email validation - [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) - which at least should works correctly in 99% of cases in opposite to your regexp.
2. Use [`parse_url()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get hostname from email address and check whether it ends with `mycompany.com`:

   ```
   $hostname = parse_url($email, PHP_URL_HOST);

   if (substr($hostname, strlen('mycompany.com') * -1)) == 'mycompany.com') {
       // ends with "mycompany.com"
   }
   ```
3. Combine above to check whether given email address meets your criteria.